# Should we migrate all new Tor questions?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

Stackexchange has a new beta site dedicated to [Tor](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions). Although i have [questioned](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11796/does-this-proposal-have-significant-overlap-with-it-security) the site's overlap with IT Security, it went ahead to beta anyway.

I think we should migrate all new Tor questions over to the beta site to help out with the numbers a little. I suggest flagging all new questions tagged with [tor](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tor) for moderator attention.

Comment: 1) Migration of old questions is discouraged 2) Migration to beta sites is discouraged 3) Migration of questions which are on-topic on both sites is discouraged => I certainly wouldn't migrate our old questions to a really new site like tor.se.

Comment: Related: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/

Comment: ["We migrate questions when they **do not belong** on a site, not when they *may* fit better on another site. . ."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/84250/228098) Granted, the question it answers is different, but the answer is applicable here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it currently is on topic here, let's not migrate existing questions over.

For new questions, the process should be the same as for other clashes (such as Astronomy, Space and Physics, or even for Security and Cryptography):

Will it get better answers here or on Tor.SE? If we think it will work there, mods can migrate it, but we only want to do that if it isn't getting any good answers here.

Answer (score 5):

No. Since it's beta, we cannot normally migrate it to it. The mods can just look the other way while we rack more Tor questions here.

Eventually, the new Tor.SE will slowly sufficate and **die**

Comment: Well, now *there's* a positive outlook!

Comment: ... quick, let's get him an appeasing position of apparent power and keep him far away from us....